# Openerp - How to set default value for fields.function

Tags: function, field, default, odoo

How can i set default value for a function field. I tried to create a function but it is never  executed.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you please share some code? One idea is to return a default value in the _default_get function.

Comment: can you please show the function or please tell what what exactly your function does

Comment: Field --> 'test': fields.function(_set_test, type='char', string='Test')  default -->  _defaults = {
  'test': _get_default_test
     }  function -->     def _get_default_test(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        print "\ndefault called"

Comment: I am not using this anymore as but still interested in the answer.

Comment: recently i added a boolean function field and added default function for that field in _defaults and it works :). whenever i create a record function defined in _defaults gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me try this,

```
def _get_test(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    print "\n\nget function call Default" 
    res = 'Pooja'
    return res


def _set_test(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    print "\n\nset function call"  
    for i in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[i.id] = 'bhavesh'
    return res

_columns = {
    'test': fields.function(_set_test, type='char', string='Test'),
}

_defaults = {
    'test': _get_test, 
}
```

Comment: Hello, when you create a new record you will see that, field value is 'Pooja'. After save that record you will get that field value is 'bhavesh'. Hope this will help you.